# Extraer columnas de un csv y ordenarlas

Tags: python, csv, filewriter, filereader

Tengo un csv con 15 columnas, quiero extraer dos de estas y ordenar el nuevo csv por orden alfabético de una de las columnas.
Es decir, si tras extraer las dos columnas en un nuevo csv tengo algo así:

```
id | fruta
01 | manzana
02 | naranja
03 | manzana
04 | fresa
05 | fresa
06 | manzana
07 | manzana
08 | naranja
09 | fresa
10 | cereza
```

Lo que yo quiero conseguir es:

```
id | fruta
10 | cereza
04 | fresa
05 | fresa
09 | fresa
01 | manzana
03 | manzana
06 | manzana
07 | manzana
02 | naranja
08 | naranja
```

Y a continuación imprimir el número de cada uno de ellos, es decir, en este caso, algo con una estructura similar a:

```
cereza 1
fresa 3
manzana 4
naranja 2
```

Consigo llegar a imprimir las columnas que quiero de la siguiente manera:

```
input_file = 'food.csv'
output_file = 'fruits.csv'
   
file = open(input_file, 'r')
new_file = open(output_file, 'w')
csv_reader = csv.DictReader(file)
for line in csv_reader:
    print(line['fruits'])
    print(line['food_id'])
```

Ahora lo que me gustaría es tener un csv con esos dos únicos parámetros, con la estructura de un csv. (He conseguido guardarlo como un txt, y no se entiende nada)

Comment: yo uso pandas, y lo haria asi. import pandas as pd df = pd.read_csv("frutas.csv") df = df.sort_values("id", ascending = True) df el resto lo harias tu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta situación se asemeja bastante a una que tuve hace algunos meses, por lo cual te compartiré prácticamente la misma implementación que desarrollé para conseguir la solución.

Primero te muestro cómo es la utilización de esta implementación en el código cliente:

```py
fruit_data = FruitData(source='fruits.csv')
fruit_data.sort_by_name()
print(fruit_data)
print(fruit_data.get_fruits_count())
```

... y la salida por pantalla del mismo:

```
id | fruta
10 | cereza
04 | fresa
05 | fresa
09 | fresa
01 | manzana
03 | manzana
06 | manzana
07 | manzana
02 | naranja
08 | naranja

[('cereza', 1), ('fresa', 3), ('manzana', 4), ('naranja', 2)]
```

La clase `FruitData` depende únicamente de módulos de la *stdlib*, y contiene lo siguiente:

```py
from collections import Counter
from csv import DictReader
from operator import itemgetter


class FruitData:
    FIELD_NAMES = ('id', 'fruta')

    def __init__(self, source):
        self._rows = list(self.extract_rows_from(source))
        self._id = itemgetter('id')
        self._name = itemgetter('fruta')

    @staticmethod
    def extract_rows_from(file_name):
        with open(file_name) as csvfile:
            yield from DictReader(csvfile)

    @property
    def rows(self):
        return [
            (self._id(fruit), self._name(fruit))
            for fruit in self._rows
        ]

    def sort_by_name(self):
        self._rows.sort(key=self._name)

    def get_fruits_count(self):
        counter = Counter(self._name(fruit) for fruit in self._rows)
        return counter.most_common()

    def __str__(self):
        rows_including_header = [self.FIELD_NAMES, *self.rows]
        return '\n'.join(
            ' | '.join(row) for row in rows_including_header
        )
```

Creo que el código se entiende bastante bien (bueno, de verdad espero que así sea) pero de igual manera puedo destacar los siguientes elementos en él:

- Se tiene una clase `FruitData`, cuyo método de inicialización (`__init__`) espera un argumento llamado `source`, que es el nombre del archivo de donde sacaremos la data. Dentro de ese mismo método se invoca un método estático (que lo es porque realmente no está ligado a la clase de ninguna otra manera que no sea mera semántica), el cual...
- ... para hacer la extracción de la data del archivo .csv, utiliza el módulo homónimo `csv`, y la clase `DictReader`. Los objetos de esta clase son capaces de *parsear* la información de los archivos de ese tipo y devolver las filas en forma de diccionarios.
- En consecuencia, la información de cada fila del archivo queda almacenada dentro de la lista "privada" (y nótense las comillas) `_rows`. La clase `FruitData` dispone de una `@property` llamada `rows` que sirve como interfaz pública a la información almacenada esta lista "privada".
- El método encargado de ordenar alfabéticamente las filas trabaja directamente sobre la lista `_rows`, mutando el estado interno de las instancias de la clase.
- Se asignan *callables* `itemgetter` a variables de instancia para acceder a los datos de cada campo (`'id'` y `'fruta'`) dentro de los métodos que así lo requieren.
- Para realizar el conteo de los nombres de la frutas, podemos apalancarnos en la funcionalidad de la clase `Counter`.
- Al sobreescribir el método `__str__` podemos obtener una representación de las filas tal como se deseaba, con tan solo pasar un objeto de la clase `FruitData` como argumento a `print()`.

En conclusión, tienes una clase altamente cohesiva, encapsulada y con una API de fácil manipulación en el código cliente (como se demostró al inicio de la respuesta).

Comment: Gracias pero esta respuesta serviría en este caso, pero no para un caso genérico.
Quiero decir, si el input en vez de frutas, son carnes, por ejemplo, esto no funcionaría. Además seguiría faltando el principal paso que era el de generar un nuevo csv con dos únicas columnas. Consigo imprimirlas, pero no guardarlas en un nuevo csv

Comment: El código que te compartí es fácilmente generalizable. Sin embargo, no lo hice así porque la pregunta habla de un input específico. En lo personal, siempre intento seguir el principio YAGNI y evitar abstracciones y optimizaciones prematuras. Con respecto a guardarlas en un nuevo archivo CSV, puedes pasar la variable `_row` a [DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) y listo.